# Rest websevice response is null using apache cxf

Tags: java, web-services, rest, cxf

I have tried out rest webservice using Apache CXF. I'm performing a create operation. i'm able to create, While returning response in json and xml format, i'm not getting any value. My service and serviceImplementation is below.
service class:

```
@Path("/location/")
@WebService
public interface LocationService {

    @WebMethod
    @POST
    @Path("location")
    @Produces({"application/xml","application/json"})
    @Descriptions({
        @Description(value = "stores a new location data", target = DocTarget.METHOD),
        @Description(value = "the newly created location data", target = DocTarget.RETURN)
    })
    public LocationData createLocation(@Valid LocationData locationData) throws DuplicateLocationException;

}
```

ServiceImplementation:

```
@Service("locationService")
public class LocationServiceEndpoint implements LocationService {

    @Override
    public LocationData createLocation(LocationData locationData) {

        setNewID(locationData);
        return locationData;
    }

    private void setNewID(LocationData locationData) {
        // setting the ID
        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        locationData.setId(id);

    }
}
```

BeanClass:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "LocationData")
public class LocationData {

    private String id;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-mm-dd")
    private Date date;
    @NotNull
    private String timezone;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 20, min = 5)
    private String location;

    public void setTimezone(String timezone) {
        this.timezone = timezone;
    }

    public String getTimezone() {
        return timezone;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb, Locale.US);
        formatter.format("ID:%s\nLocation:%s\nDate:%s\nTime zone:%s\n", getId(), getLocation(), getDate(), getTimezone());

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

my cxf.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
       xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">


     <!-- REST -->
     <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
     <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/osgi/cxf-extension-osgi.xml" />

     <!-- SOAP -->
     <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />


    <context:component-scan base-package="org.exampledriven.cxfexample"/>

    <!-- PROVIDERS -->

    <bean id="wadlProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.model.wadl.WadlGenerator">
        <property name="applicationTitle" value="CXF Test sample application" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jaxbProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider">
        <property name="marshallerProperties" ref="propertiesMap" />
    </bean>

    <util:map id="propertiesMap">
        <entry key="jaxb.formatted.output">
            <value type="java.lang.Boolean">true</value>
        </entry>
    </util:map>

    <bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JSONProvider">
        <property name="namespaceMap" ref="jsonNamespaceMap" />
    </bean>

    <util:map id="jsonNamespaceMap" map-class="java.util.Hashtable">
        <entry key="http://www.example.org/books" value="b" />
    </util:map>

    <!-- REST SERVER -->

    <jaxrs:server id="restContainer" address="/rest">
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean="jaxbProvider" />
            <ref bean="jsonProvider" />
            <ref bean="wadlProvider" />
        </jaxrs:providers>
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="locationService"/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        </jaxrs:extensionMappings>       
    </jaxrs:server>

    <!-- SOAP SERVER -->

    <jaxws:endpoint id="location" implementor="#locationService" address="/soap" />

    <!-- CXF Message logging -->

    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:features>
            <cxf:logging/>
        </cxf:features>
    </cxf:bus> 

    <!-- CLIENT -->
    <!--
    <jaxrs:client id="locationClient"
         address="http://localhost:8080/rest/"
         serviceClass="org.exampledriven.cxfexample.webservice.LocationService"
         inheritHeaders="true">
         <jaxrs:headers>
             <entry key="Accept" value="application/xml"/>
         </jaxrs:headers>
    </jaxrs:client> 
     --> 

    <!-- Spring Validation -->
    <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>

</beans>
```

SOAP service is working fine. Rest is not producing data in XML and JSON format.

Please help!!!

**LOG**

```
2016-12-25 22:27:21,427 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] - /cxf/rest/location/location.json at position 1 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-12-25 22:27:21,428 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] - No HttpSession currently exists
2016-12-25 22:27:21,428 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2016-12-25 22:27:21,428 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] - /cxf/rest/location/location.json at position 2 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2016-12-25 22:27:21,428 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] - /cxf/rest/location/location.json at position 3 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2016-12-25 22:27:21,428 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] - /cxf/rest/location/location.json at position 4 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-12-25 22:27:21,428 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] - /cxf/rest/location/location.json at position 5 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2016-12-25 22:27:21,428 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter] - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2016-12-25 22:27:21,429 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] - /cxf/rest/location/location.json at position 6 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2016-12-25 22:27:21,429 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] - /cxf/rest/location/location.json at position 7 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2016-12-25 22:27:21,429 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] - /cxf/rest/location/location.json at position 8 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2016-12-25 22:27:21,429 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : '/cxf/rest/location/location.json'; against '/rest/**'
2016-12-25 22:27:21,429 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor] - Public object - authentication not attempted
2016-12-25 22:27:21,429 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] - /cxf/rest/location/location.json reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2016-12-25 22:27:21,430 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController] - Service http request on thread: Thread[qtp1179689991-19,5,main]
2016-12-25 22:27:21,430 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination] - Create a new message for processing
2016-12-25 22:27:21,431 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.transport.http.Headers] - Request Headers: {Accept=[*/*], accept-encoding=[gzip, deflate, br], Accept-Language=[en-US,en;q=0.8], connection=[keep-alive], Content-Length=[0], content-type=[application/json], Host=[localhost:8080], Origin=[chrome-extension://eipdnjedkpcnlmmdfdkgfpljanehloah], User-Agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36]}
2016-12-25 22:27:21,432 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.transport.https.CertConstraintsInterceptor@4ee68c5b to phase pre-stream
2016-12-25 22:27:21,432 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] - Chain org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain@1125ee5 was created. Current flow:
  receive [LoggingInInterceptor]
  pre-stream [CertConstraintsInterceptor]
  unmarshal [JAXRSInInterceptor]
  pre-logical [OneWayProcessorInterceptor]
  invoke [ServiceInvokerInterceptor]
  post-invoke [OutgoingChainInterceptor]

2016-12-25 22:27:21,432 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor@56222a2f
2016-12-25 22:27:21,433 INFO [org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor] - Inbound Message
----------------------------
ID: 8
Address: http://localhost:8080/cxf/rest/location/location.json
Encoding: ISO-8859-1
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: application/json
Headers: {Accept=[*/*], accept-encoding=[gzip, deflate, br], Accept-Language=[en-US,en;q=0.8], connection=[keep-alive], Content-Length=[0], content-type=[application/json], Host=[localhost:8080], Origin=[chrome-extension://eipdnjedkpcnlmmdfdkgfpljanehloah], User-Agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36]}
--------------------------------------
2016-12-25 22:27:21,433 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.transport.https.CertConstraintsInterceptor@4ee68c5b
2016-12-25 22:27:21,433 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor@185755a4
2016-12-25 22:27:21,434 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils] - Trying to select a resource class, request path : /location/location
2016-12-25 22:27:21,434 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils] - Trying to select a resource operation on the resource class org.exampledriven.cxfexample.webservice.LocationServiceEndpoint
2016-12-25 22:27:21,435 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils] - No method match, method name : readLocation, request path : /location, method @Path : /rest, HTTP Method : POST, method HTTP Method : GET, ContentType : application/json, method @Consumes : */*,, Accept : application/json,, method @Produces : */*,.
2016-12-25 22:27:21,435 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils] - Resource operation createLocation may get selected
2016-12-25 22:27:21,436 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils] - Resource operation createLocation on the resource class org.exampledriven.cxfexample.webservice.LocationServiceEndpoint has been selected
2016-12-25 22:27:21,437 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor] - Request path is: /location/location
2016-12-25 22:27:21,437 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor] - Request HTTP method is: POST
2016-12-25 22:27:21,437 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor] - Request contentType is: application/json
2016-12-25 22:27:21,437 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor] - Accept contentType is: application/json
2016-12-25 22:27:21,437 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor] - Found operation: createLocation
2016-12-25 22:27:21,515 WARN [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper] - WebApplicationException has been caught : org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0 of 
2016-12-25 22:27:21,515 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper] - org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0 of 
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0 of 
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JSONProvider.readFrom(JSONProvider.java:236)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:1036)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameter(JAXRSUtils.java:616)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameters(JAXRSUtils.java:580)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:238)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:123)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:207)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:213)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:154)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:126)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:185)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1359)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1330)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:970)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:1054)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:529)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0 of 
    at org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(MappedXMLInputFactory.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.jettison.AbstractXMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(AbstractXMLInputFactory.java:106)
    at org.codehaus.jettison.AbstractXMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(AbstractXMLInputFactory.java:93)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JSONUtils.createStreamReader(JSONUtils.java:141)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JSONProvider.createReader(JSONProvider.java:257)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JSONProvider.createReader(JSONProvider.java:248)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JSONProvider.readFrom(JSONProvider.java:212)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0 of 
    at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:439)
    at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:170)
    at org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(MappedXMLInputFactory.java:43)
    ... 67 more
2016-12-25 22:27:21,520 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OneWayProcessorInterceptor@5f636f35
2016-12-25 22:27:21,520 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor@1989edd8
2016-12-25 22:27:21,520 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor@7b6555c4
2016-12-25 22:27:21,521 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor] - Interceptors contributed by bus: [org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor@7d75751c]
2016-12-25 22:27:21,521 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor] - Interceptors contributed by service: []
2016-12-25 22:27:21,521 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor] - Interceptors contributed by endpoint: [org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor@18c104aa]
2016-12-25 22:27:21,522 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor] - Interceptors contributed by binding: [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSOutInterceptor@146698d5]
2016-12-25 22:27:21,522 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] - Chain org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain@55fb1415 was created. Current flow:
  prepare-send [MessageSenderInterceptor]
  pre-stream [LoggingOutInterceptor]
  marshal [JAXRSOutInterceptor]

2016-12-25 22:27:21,522 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor@18c104aa
2016-12-25 22:27:21,523 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor@1cea4141 to phase prepare-send-ending
2016-12-25 22:27:21,524 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] - Chain org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain@55fb1415 was modified. Current flow:
  prepare-send [MessageSenderInterceptor]
  pre-stream [LoggingOutInterceptor]
  marshal [JAXRSOutInterceptor]
  prepare-send-ending [MessageSenderEndingInterceptor]

2016-12-25 22:27:21,524 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor@7d75751c
2016-12-25 22:27:21,524 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSOutInterceptor@146698d5
2016-12-25 22:27:21,527 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor@1cea4141
2016-12-25 22:27:21,528 INFO [org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor] - Outbound Message
---------------------------
ID: 8
Response-Code: 500
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {Date=[Sun, 25 Dec 2016 16:57:21 GMT], Content-Length=[0]}
--------------------------------------
2016-12-25 22:27:21,532 DEBUG [org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController] - Finished servicing http request on thread: Thread[qtp1179689991-19,5,main]
2016-12-25 22:27:21,532 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter] - Chain processed normally
2016-12-25 22:27:21,532 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2016-12-25 22:27:21,532 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

**Update:**
I have added another method in service for performing read operation and its corresponding logic in implementation class. Now i'm able to get response in xml and json format. I have added the below method

```
    @WebMethod
@GET
@Path("{location}")
@Descriptions({
    @Description(value = "returns a location data ", target = DocTarget.METHOD),
    @Description(value = "the location data", target = DocTarget.RETURN)
})
public LocationData readLocation(@Description(value = "the string representation of the location") @PathParam("location") @NotNull @Size(max=10, min=5) String location) throws LocationNotFoundException;
```

But i want response in json and xml format while performing create operation itself

Output:[image: Instead of Delhi, i will be having location, when i click on URL i get blank page]

Instead of Delhi, i will be having 'location', when i click on URL i get blank page

Comment: I have posted a summary of the comments as answer, and seem comments have been flagged as obsolete. Please consider to mark the answer as accepted or upvote if it has been helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Solution in comments)

The underlying problem is the need to invoke a JAX-RS method using a URL link

```
@POST
@Path("location")
@Produces({"application/xml","application/json"})
public LocationData createLocation(@Valid LocationData locationData) throws DuplicateLocationException;
```

**It is not possible to send a `POST` request with JSON clicking in a URL.** Click a link or introduce a URL in the browser toolbar executes a `GET` request.

The second method works because uses GET and a URL path `/rest/location/{location`}. This method can not receive JSON data but can return JSON.

You have to use AJAX yo invoke a REST service with `POST` sending json or XML. Alternatively you could post data clicking in a URL using query parameters

```
rest/location/create?location=Delhi&timezone=
```

But this is not very orthodoxe